# Contar caracteres numa string a partir de uma busca feita na propria string

Tags: php

Boa tarde a todos!
Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para descobrir como eu faço a contagem de caracteres em uma string, passando uma referência na própria string, exemplo:
Possuo a string `19:30` e queria que depois dos `:` verificasse se o numero de caracteres é maior que 2, se for, faria uma coisa, se não faria outra.
Sei fazer a parte das condições, só estou esbarrando nessa duvida, de como contar caracteres após uma referência.
Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Se o caracter "separador" for único dentro da string, podes usar explode e depois um strlen.
$exp = explode(":", $string);
$conta = strlen($exp[1]);
---- EDITANDO ---
FIquei com receio de deixar incompleto, pois tu disse que o resto estava ok. Mas segue:
if($conta > 2){
faz uma coisa }else{
faz outra coisa }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você pode usar a função `strpos()` do php, ela encontra a posição da primeira ocorrência de uma substring na string.
Se não encontrar nenhuma ocorrência, essa função retorna `false`.

A solução para você é essa:

```
$string =  '19:30';

$pos    =  strpos( $string, ':' );

if( !is_bool( $pos ) ) {
    $pos += 1;
    echo strlen( substr( $string, $pos) );
}
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado @Duque, como você disse, foi a solução!
Obrigado de verdade! :)